# 130 years Genesis 5:3

Tags: genesis, adam

In Genesis 5:3, where Adam's age is stated as 130 years old, is there by chance any alternative, maybe gematria-type alternative meaning for 130?  I don't mean a different age, but a word that 130 could also reference in addition to an age of 130 years?  Double-meaning?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take to tour to understand how this site works.

Comment: The problem with Gematria is that it only came into existence after the Bible was finished, 2nd century or later.  To interpret text according to an after thought is made hermeneutic.

Comment: @Dottard, that's fascinating.  What evidence do you have for that claim.  It would be great to be able to conclusively shut that one down.

Comment: @GusL. Cabbalism was a medieval practice.  While the association of letters with number is (as some dubiously claim) goes back much further (without much evidence) Cabbalism as applied to Hebrew scriptures can only be traced several centuries after Christ.

Comment: Let me provide an interesting example: Rev 13:18 says the number of the beast is ἑξακόσιοι ἑξήκοντα ἕξ (six hundred sixty six).  It is only in medieval texts  that this number has become χξς’.  As best as I can determine, the Greek and Hebrew text never uses letters as numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this shows that it was not in use during the Hebrew Persian period or Hellenism.  Pythagoras was contemporary to Babylonian exile and influenced from Greece to Egypt to India through Alexander.  He had all sorts of wonky numerology stuff.  Also, the Babylonian cosmology was built on cycles of 7 and sexagesimal numerology.  The fact that Cain's genealogy is 7 (completed and ended) and that Adam's has 10, both ending with three sons seems like the author at least intended some mathematical/numerological symmetry/significance to the text.

Comment: The fact that Matthew points out that the genealogy of Jesus repeats the figure of fourteen three times, indicates that certain numbers, in certain circumstances, are to be noticed.

Comment: עין - the 16 the letter, interpreted eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://www.billheidrick.com/works/hgm2/hg0130.htm) to Bill Heidrick's list gives about thirty possible meanings associated with the number 130, and its primes - 2, 5, 13 - based on the Gematria idea and system.

I have no idea how authoritative this work is, or how reliable.

Nor do I know how one would choose between the variety of meanings.

But the link is there and the list is there, if you wish to access it.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) also has a lot of information about the history of the subject, but opinions differ as to whether, in fact, there is any real 'embedding' of a 'code' into the Hebrew scriptures.

Some see it in the text and others think it to be a fanciful theory, not borne out by the spirituality of the content of the holy text.

Numbers are used, it is true, in an allusory way in scripture, the numbers seven and ten and six and five, for example, often pointing to a spiritual hint of meaning, but my understanding is that that is a different matter from the Gematria 'embedded code' concept.

That Matthew draws attention to the triple recurrence of the number fourteen in the genealogy of Jesus with which he begins his book, indicates that, in certain cases, numbers are to be noticed. Again, in the book of Revelation, numbers clearly have spiritual signification.

But to extend that into a concept which supposes that every mentioned number must be 'translated' into a supposed code, is another thing altogether.

Comment: Thanks.  I've met a guy named Adam and he knew the meaning of my name, he said 130 in the bible had to do with a mirror, your website says to resemble, so thats probably what he's talking about lol.  Thanks :)

Comment: @JennPQ And, also, the Hebrew root of Adam, and also Edom, is red or earthy. Which has, of course, a spiritual meaning in itself.